# What is the probability measure in strong law of large number?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

The statement is that $P(\bar{X}_n \to \mu)=1$. $\{\bar{X}_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables, which is essentially a sequence of functions on $\Omega$, the domain of all outcomes. Mathematically, Strong LLN states that this sequence of functions converges to the constant function $\mu$ pointwise almost everywhere. "Almost everywhere" here is with respect to probability measure $P$. But how exactly is $P$ defined here. It seems that distribution of $\{\bar{X}_n\}$ changes for each $n$. So where does this $P$ come from.

Comment: This $P$ is defined on an abstract probability space which has enough "richness" to define a sequence of iid random variables in the first place.

Comment: Can you give a precise mathematical definition for $P$ or point me to a source for that?

Comment: People rarely explicitly define probability spaces except in very elementary examples. Occasionally theoretical work is needed to ensure that a probability space with enough richness for what you want to do actually exists, but usually we just take it for granted that there is a suitable space out there for our setup. An overkill way to prove this particular case is to use the Kolmogorov extension theorem.

Comment: By the way, the naive way to do this is to just take a space $\Omega$ where you can define $X_1$, take the direct product $\Omega^{\mathbb{N}}$, and then define the probability measure as the extension of the probability measure on the "cylinder sets", i.e. the products $\prod_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ where $A_i$ are measurable subsets of $\Omega$, where $P \left ( \prod_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right )$ is defined to be $\prod_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i)$.

Comment: (Cont.) The problem is that it's not entirely obvious that this extension to a probability measure exists when you take this infinite product (whereas it is more or less obvious in the finite case). This is why you have to go through machinery like the Kolmogorov extension theorem.